# Max device/ USB 3.0 port

Tags: 14.04, usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I wonder and I have a question: How many active device/ USB 3.0 port?

Because:

I have a USB hub 1 to 8.

I connect it to a USB 3.0 of PC but only 6/8 outputs are active.

Connecting USB 2.0 is not that.

Can any person tell me why?

Comment: How do you know only 6 of them are active? For the not working 2 ports, they're specific ports or the 7th, 8th port when you try to use them?